# how to disable multiple textboxes from another form?

Tags: c#

I have this combo box in Form1 and I need to disable some of the textboxes when the combo box value changes and there is a button to go to that form which its textboxes are getting disabled.

how can I do what I want without both of the forms showing at the same time?!

Here is the Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal Grading_Section grading;
    internal TextBox te;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        grading = new Grading_Section();
        grading.Show();
        te = TxtAddress;
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FindControl fc = new FindControl();
        Grading_Section gr = new Grading_Section();
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "MSC")
        {
            ((TextBox)fc.Ctrl(fc.TheForm("Grading_Section"), "textBox1")).Enabled = false;
            ((TextBox)fc.Ctrl(fc.TheForm("Grading_Section"), "textBox2")).Enabled = false;
            ((TextBox)fc.Ctrl(fc.TheForm("Grading_Section"), "textBox3")).Enabled = false;

        }
        else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "CSP")
        {
            ((TextBox)fc.Ctrl(fc.TheForm("Grading_Section"), "textBox1")).Enabled = true;
            ((TextBox)fc.Ctrl(fc.TheForm("Grading_Section"), "textBox2")).Enabled = true;
            ((TextBox)fc.Ctrl(fc.TheForm("Grading_Section"), "textBox3")).Enabled = true;
        }

    }
    private void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        Grading_Section g = new Grading_Section();
        g.Show();    
    }
```

And this is my FindControl class:

```
 public class FindControl
    {
        Control c = null;
        Control f = null;
        public FindControl()
        {
        }
        public Control TheForm(string name)
        {
            FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;

            //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            for (int i = 0; i < fc.Count; i++)
            {

                c = null;
                if (fc[i].Name == name)
                {
                    f = fc[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ((Control)f);
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        public Control Ctrl(Control f, string name)
        {
           * for (int i = 0; i < f.Controls.Count; i++)*
            {
                if (f.Controls[i].Name == name)
                {
                    c = f.Controls[i];
                    break;
                }
                if (c == null)
                {
                    if (f.Controls[i].Controls.Count > 0)
                        Ctrl(f.Controls[i], name);
                }
                if (c != null)
                    break;
            }
            return (c);
        }
    }
```

So far I find this code but the only way that it works is to show both of the forms at the same time otherwise it shows this error:

when I delete this line the error pop up:"grading.Show();

"NullReference Exception was unhandled,An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe"

The Error accrued from this line:

- for (int i = 0; i < f.Controls.Count; i++)*

Comment: yeah, your code works only if both forms are visible, because you're going through open forms collection. If you want to disable it on second form, you should pass some param to that other form's constructor or something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Visible = false;
    Grading_Section g = new Grading_Section();
    g.DisableTextBoxes(comboboxValue);
    g.Show();    
}
```

In the form Garding_Section, you should create a method like this :

```
public void DisableTextBoxes(string value)
{
 if(value == "a")
  {
    //disabele related texboxes
  }
  else if(value == "b")
  {
   //disable related textboxes.
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.